# Get folder names/access of Google Drive using Zend's GData library

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to retrieve values from Google Spreadsheet using Zend's GData library. I can retrieve values from Sheets. Now I would like to get a list of folders. So that I can retrieve values from Sheets within that specific folder. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Use [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) and include query with mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' while sending request. With this request, you can get list of folders in your drive.